# Is it possible to create Hyperlink that can open a user form in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have a worksheet with a hyperlink and what I want to do is to open a UserForm when I click on this hyperlink.

```
=HYPERLINK("frmReferral","Go for Referral")
```

frmReferral is the form name that I created in this excel workbook. When I clicked on "Go for Referral" link, it's return "Cannot open the specified file.".
Is there anyway to do this without using VBA. If there is no option, I will try to do this with VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acquire this with VBA. Adjust code below to refer to your cell containing hyperlink. Make sure you enter this code in `Worksheet module` of selected sheet, not `regular module`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("B1").Value = "YES" Then UserForm1.Show 'adjust B1 range to your cell
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kresimir L.
I still have tricky one :(. My Hyperlink is based on another cell value that user typed "Yes" or "No".
When user typed "Yes", the Hyperlink appear and then when user clicks on Hyperlink that go to UserForm. If user typed "No" than we don't need to show Hyperlink and as well as for UserForm.
Below is Hyperlink formula I used
`=IF(OR([@5]="No",[@5]=""),HYPERLINK(""), HYPERLINK("#ReferralForm!A1","Go for Referral"))`

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. Please adjust range B1 to range in which user types YES/NO.